# what is legacy for: numpy.set_printoptions(legacy='1.13')

Tags: python, numpy, printing

I don't quite understand what legacy is for from the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html?highlight=set_printoptions#numpy.set_printoptions). Can someone explain with an example?

If I am trying to get precision to 4 decimal places, why not just use this?

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
>>> np.array([1.123456789])
[1.1235]
```

Comment: Did you write code several years ago with the `numpy` version was 1.13?  Are you trying to replicate some behavior from then?  If not, don't worry about this option.

Answer (score 2):

If set to the string ‘1.13’ enables 1.13 legacy printing mode. This approximates numpy 1.13 print output by including a space in the sign position of floats and different behavior for 0d arrays. If set to False, disables legacy mode.

So if you're trying to get an output set by previous numpy versions just add:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(legacy='1.13')
```

before you print your numpy expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't try...

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, legacy='1.13')

np.array([1.123456789])
array([ 1.1235])
```

Notice the space where one might have a + or - sign.
Experiment to see various inputs.